# Configure my local flask server to be available to other devices under same wifi network

Tags: flask, networking, server, localhost

From most of the resources, I gathered-

1. If I declare 0.0.0.0 as host and 5000 as port explicitly,other devices under my wifi network should access it, but when I type `http://0.0.0.0:5000/` from another machine(my windows laptop), it didn't work.
2. port 5000 needs to be open. If not then I should open that.
   That didn't work for me either.
3. Perhaps `debug=True` parameter should be removed from Flask's `run()` method as dev server shouldn't be publicly available. Still no luck!

What else could be the problem as the following isn't working for me-

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

I know, this question has been asked couple of times, but none of the suggestions worked for me. So, please help me access my flask Restful API through other devices as I want to test the service having a web application and mobile application as clients.

Comment: to access the app on other devices use ip address of machine running the app and then the port e.g `192.168.1.23:5000` and flask app should have `app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)`

Comment: Thanks that worked. Can you please post your comment as an answer. Also just address that the ip address should be the private one, not public.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Flask dev server should not be used in production as it is not designed to be efficient and secure. [Flask Deployment](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/deploying/)

To make the flask dev server visible on LAN/WLAN add the `host` parameter to run on machine's IP Address

```py
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

To Access the web server use private ip address(LAN/WLAN) of the machine running the flask server `192.168.1.23:5000`